# Putting a word at each end of the text of a textfile in Unix

Tags: unix

I just want to know what is the code in Unix if i had **Text.txt**, for example, and it contains:

```
KERV KERV KERV KERV KERV
kerv
```

As an output I want to add `,` at each end of the word as follows:

```
KERV, KERV, KERV, KERV, KERV,
kerv,
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with sed,

```
 sed 's/\(\w\+\)/&,/g'
```

Comment: Thank you. What if i want to replace all ','(comma) on my text file with a " "(blank)?

Comment: You can use `sed 's/,/ /g'`

Comment: Thank you! I'm using it now! Thanks for your help Sir!

Answer (score 0):

Use this sed command.

On Mac:

```
sed -E 's/([^ ]+)/\1,/g'
```

or on other `*nix`:

```
sed -r 's/([^ ]+)/\1,/g'
```

Comment: Thank you. What if i want to replace all ','(comma) on my text file with a " "(blank)?

Comment: In that case you can use: `sed 's/,/ /g'`

Comment: Thank you! I'm using it now! Thanks for your help Sir!

Answer (score -1):

To do that you need to read about [SED](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/unix-sed-tutorial-replace-text-inside-a-file-using-substitute-command/) , this will help you, after you understand it its a great tool!

you can replace " " with ", "

Comment: As much as possible i want to retain the spaces. I just want to add ',' at each end of the word at my text files.

Comment: What happens at the end of a line, if we were to use `sed` as you propose?

Comment: you can do anything you want at the end of the line, just read about it